# Coordinate derivation of non-metricity tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

In the lecture of my course of Theories of gravity the definition of non-metricity tensor is:

$$Q(w,v,z)=-\nabla_{w}g(v,z)+g(\nabla_{w}v,z)+g(w,\nabla_{w}z).$$

1. First question: where could i find this definition? I have not found this definition anywhere so far.
2. Second question: how to derive the coordinate expression  $$Q(e_{\mu},e_{\nu},e_{\rho})=-\nabla_{\mu}g_{\nu\rho}$$ from the definition above? is there any way to say that $g(\nabla_{\mu}e_{\nu},e_{\rho})=0$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The non-metricity tensor is generally defined as the covariant derivative of the metric tensor :

\begin{equation}
\nabla g = Q
\end{equation}

As the metric is a rank $(0, 2)$ tensor, its covariant derivative will be a rank $(0,3)$ tensor, so that we can apply to it three vectors as arguments :

\begin{equation}
(\nabla g)(X,Y,Z) = Q(X,Y,Z)
\end{equation}

We can inspect instead the covariant derivative of the product $g(X, Y)$. As this is a scalar, its covariant derivative is simply an ordinary derivative, mapping scalars to rank $(0,1)$ tensors. Since the covariant derivative obeys the Leibniz rule, and covariant derivatives commute with contraction, we have

\begin{equation}
\nabla(g(X, Y)) = \nabla(g) (X,Y) + g(\nabla X, Y) + g(X, \nabla Y)
\end{equation}

The first term is our non-metricity tensor. If we furthermore apply a third vector $Z$ to be the direction of our covariant derivative (so that they are the operator $\nabla_Z$), we obtain the appropriate map. Reorganizing our expression a bit :

\begin{equation}
Q (X, Y, Z) = \nabla_Z(g(X, Y)) - g(\nabla_Z X, Y) - g(X, \nabla_Z Y)
\end{equation}

There is a sign difference here, which makes sense since your definition seems to be actually $\nabla g = -Q$. The coordinate versions of these are then

\begin{eqnarray}
Q(e_\mu, e_\nu, e_\rho) &=& -\nabla_{e_\rho} g(e_\mu, e_\nu)\\
&=& - \partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu} + {\Gamma^\sigma}_{\rho\nu} g_{\mu\sigma} + {\Gamma^\sigma}_{\rho\mu} g_{\nu\sigma}
\end{eqnarray}

and then on the other side, using the fact that $g(X,Y)$ is a scalar,

\begin{eqnarray}
-\nabla_{e_\rho}(g(e_\mu, e_\nu)) + g(\nabla_{e_\rho} e_\mu, e_\nu) + g(e_\mu , \nabla_{e_\rho} e_\nu) &=& -\nabla_{e_\rho} g_{\mu\nu} + g({\Gamma^\sigma}_{\rho\mu} e_\sigma, e_\nu) + g(e_\mu , {\Gamma^\sigma}_{\rho\nu} e_\sigma)\\
&=& - \partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu} + {\Gamma^\sigma}_{\rho\mu} g_{\sigma\nu} + {\Gamma^\sigma}_{\rho\nu} g_{\mu\sigma}
\end{eqnarray}

Up to some dummy variables, those are indeed the same expressions